# How to redirect to the same page after login

Tags: php, authentication

I have a cart products page, if a person clicks on a product add to cart button they will be redirected to the login page.

After a successful login, I need to send the user back to same products page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple solution would be to store the "return" URL in a session variable before you kick to the login page. The login page would check for the presence of the session variable and then unset it prior to using a header location re-direct to return the user to the URL in question.

For example on the login page you'd use:

```
// Successfully logged in...
$destURL = $_SESSION['kickurl'] ? $_SESSION['kickurl'] : '/index.php';
unset($_SESSION['kickurl']);
header('Location: ' . $destURL);
exit();
```

Comment: @Navruk Thanks - hope it goes well. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You should track the url of each page : 
as :`<?php $_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>`

and now use that one :
`<?php session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['url'])) 
   $url = $_SESSION['url']; // url for last page visited.
else 
   $url = "index.php"; // page you want to redirect by default
header("Location: http://abc.com/$url"); ?.`

Answer (score 1):

Send the url to return to as a GET paramter in the redirect to the login page:

```
/login.php?return_url=%2Fcart%2Fproducts.php
```

In login.php you decode the return_url parameter (/cart/products.php) and send the user there on successful login.

Answer (score 1):

When you redirect to the login page, put the URL that you intercepted (often called a return URL) into a session variable (or some other storage as appropriate). Then, when login is complete you can redirect to this URL.

You sometimes see the return URL in website querystrings during a logon process. For example if you go to docs.google.com when you're not logged into any google account you can see a "continue" value in the querystring as below:

https ://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=writely&passive=1209600&continue=http://docs.google.com/&followup=http://docs.google.com/&ltmpl=homepage

Answer (score 0):

Keep the

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirurl" value="<? echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>" />
```

and get `redirurl` value in form post.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['redirurl']))
   $url = $_REQUEST['redirurl']; // holds url for last page visited.
else
   $url = "myprofile.php"; // default page

header("Location:$url");
```

`redirurl` stores the previous Pageurl. keep the session for register and login pages so that it doesn't copy those Page URL.

Answer (score -1):

You can send the user back to the page they came from, using their browser's referer:

`header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);`

Comment: Unreliable; There's no guarantee that the browser supplies this value or that it is correct.

Comment: That is, if the HTTP_REFERER is a local url, not a remote one ;)